# Testing php code while running script

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am new to phpunit. I have developed some test cases for my php code and I am able to run them.

Is it possible to run those test cases when the classes, for which test cases are generated, are used during actual software is running?

For example, when I run software and a class A's method myMethod() is called. I want test cases for that method to run, too.

I have searched a lot but have not found anything that says how to do it. So I wonder whether it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do such a thing, because it will immensely slow down your software. Typically your software (and your tests) only changes when you deploy a new version to your production server. You could use an continues integration (CI) server which you can configure to automatically run your testsuite whenever you commit to VCS or before you deploy.